# Is it safe to create a singleton express app instance

Tags: node.js, express, singleton, pm2

I am creating an express app. In this app I have routes in different files like users.js, orders.js. I also have some files that I call services. These services have code that uses the app instance. This is how I load a service in a route.

```
var mySvcFile = require('./services/mySvc');
route.get('/abc-route', (req, res) => {
    var mySvc = mySvcFile(req.app);
});
```

In this code I am importing a function from services and in route I pass the app instance to get the service instance.

What if I simply make the express's app instance singleton and import it anywhere I needed. This way I don't have to pass the app instance.
Will it be a bad Idea to use a singleton app instance.

I am using pm2 and will have multitple instances of my server.